# Laptop Suspend not working 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend

On my Lenovo IdeaPad 5 laptop using Ubuntu 20.04.3 daily

Suspend on lid close and suspend with the power button do not work

Suspend from the Power Off/Log Out menu selection does work

I originally said 21.10 daily, but I just installed 20.04.3 and I'm having the same issues

Comment: Please file three proper bug reports on the bug tracker. AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker. Thank you for helping to test Ubuntu!

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *impish* indri [21.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.10 is 14 October 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-schedule/18540) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're after support you should use a #ubuntu+1 site as *impish* hasn't been released yet, however if you're QA-testing and are seeking help with bug reporting, you can also use #ubuntu-quality on IRC or telegram; for help with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  If using the daily for *live* testing; you should also report on the ISO QA tracker http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/424/builds (it doesn't apply to installed systems except for the install itself; report via launchpad bug tracker for installed/usage issues)

Comment: Reread your post. There is no question. what are you wanting?  The power button thing  is common on Ubuntu. My power button shuts the machine off.

Comment: @NateT I would like it to work. There is an option for setting the power button to suspend and it doesn't work.

Comment: Run `apt info gnome-shell-extension-suspend-button`. The top line should say `gnome-shell-extension-suspend-button/focal,focal 0~git20191005-1 all` Immediately after this, on the same line, does it say `[Installed, ... ]` the ellipses would be replaced by either `Automatic` or something else, depending on install method. Do you have this? If not try it out. Read the bottom paragraph of the `apt info` command first. It is not automatically enabled. You will have to use gnome-tweak-tool or something similar. Coincidently, I was reading about this when you commented.  Wierd!

Comment: `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-suspend-button`

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Gnome Tweaks tool from the Ubuntu Software application. I am
   using version 3.34.0.
2. Run Gnome Tweaks.
3. On the **General** tab, turn on 'Suspend when laptop lid is closed'.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work